# Sony Spresenseにnuttx.spkをロード後のKey not specified.について

Tags: spresense

Spresense SDKのチュートリアルで、
ブートローダーをインストールの際に、『key not specified』が二回出力されます。

```
root@ubuntu:~/tools/kconfig-frontends/spresense/sdk# ./tools/flash.sh -e ~/spresense-binaries-v1.0.000.zip
Update succeed.
root@ubuntu:~/tools/kconfig-frontends/spresense/sdk# 
root@ubuntu:~/tools/kconfig-frontends/spresense/sdk# ./tools/flash.sh -l ../firmware/spresense -c /dev/ttyUSB0
>>> Install files ...
install -b 115200
Install ../firmware/spresense/loader.espk
Waiting for XMODEM (CRC or 1K) transfer. Ctrl-X to cancel.
....................................................................................................................115984 bytes loaded.
Key not specified.
updater# install -b 115200
Install ../firmware/spresense/gnssfw.espk
Waiting for XMODEM (CRC or 1K) transfer. Ctrl-X to cancel.
......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................429984 bytes loaded.
Key not specified.
updater# sync
updater# Restarting the board ...
reboot
```

Key not specifiedのKeyとは何をさしているのでしょうか。
ライセンスキーと思いましたが、そのようなものもありませんでした。

Helloサンプルの動作確認は完了していますが、今後の開発の時に支障が起きない為に、
質問しています。

ボードはSPRITZERを使用していますが、SONYさんの公式サイトでは名前をSPRESENSEに変更したとの事、また、Arduino IDEでのLチカは確認済みであるため、ボードの影響はないです。

何卒、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。
お問い合わせの件について、回答いたします。

一部のSPRITZER試作ボードは製品版のソフトウェアと互換性がないため、
"Key not specified" が表示されます。

大変恐れ入りますが、製品版のSPRESENSEボードでお試しいただけるでしょうか。

どうぞ、よろしくお願いいたします。